# Azure Cosmosdb with PHP batch sample fails

Tags: php, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Testing the Table samples, in the batchInsertEntitiesSample method:

```
function batchInsertEntitiesSample($tableClient, $mytable)
{
    $batchOp = new BatchOperations();
    for ($i = 2; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        $entity = new Entity();
        $entity->setPartitionKey("pk");
        $entity->setRowKey(''.$i);
        $entity->addProperty("PropertyName", EdmType::STRING, "Sample".$i);
        $entity->addProperty("Description", null, "Sample description.");
        $batchOp->addInsertEntity($mytable, $entity);
    }

    try {
        $tableClient->batch($batchOp);
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The output is always something like this:
400: Fail: Code: 400 Value: Bad Request details (if any): {"odata.error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"One of the input values is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 0b0f6445-d44c-4d82-aff5-742982f30ddc, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.20.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0\nRequestID:0b0f6445-d44c-4d82-aff5-742982f30ddc\n"}}} .

The entity is a simple string. I can't see what is missing.

The project is in https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/TableSamples.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way you can trace the request sent to Cosmos DB Table Service and the response returned? You can use a tool like Fiddler to do so. Please edit your question and include the request/response. That would help in understanding why the table service is throwing this 400 error.

Comment: The insertEntitySample method works perfectly, with the same $entity variable and $stringconnection. I think there is a problem with this $tableClient->batch($batchOp); Thanks Gaurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using this library for CosmosDB with Table API. Actually, this library is not officially validated with CosmosDB Table API (Although most of the methods should work). It only validated with Azure Storage Table. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/tables/